# Statistic Probability

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

i have this hw question but what i submit isn't right and am not sure what's the right reason behind the correct solution.

> The Gallup Poll reported that 43% of Americans are fans of professional baseball. If 7 people are selected at random, find the probability that they all are fans of professional baseball.

I have this questions and i was wondering isn't finding the prob that all of them are fans is basically P(7) and finding that out should translate to 0.43^7 = 0.00271818611107 rounded to 3 decimal 0.003 , but that solution isn't right and i am not sure how to do it

Comment: I think it must be given that Gallup Poll repoted for total how many Americans?

Comment: the asking is basically saying to find P (7 people are fans of professional baseball) but aren't like what i finding is basically that , since am finding the probability of each one being a fan and then all of them ?

Comment: Maybe they wanted three significant digits $0.000272$, not three digits after the decimal point?

Comment: Yeah, because I don't see what's wrong with the OP's answer.

Comment: @BrianTung i dont think so , I've been rounding tons of three decimal points question and so far so good this is how its supposed to go even trying online calculators gives the same answer , but as suggested maybe what am finding isn't the correct way to do it ?, i am not sure

Comment: @AbdarahmanHajabiPyroStreak: Does it hurt to try?  Because otherwise, if the issue is the distinction between Americans and people, you don't have enough information to arrive at any specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the question is asking if 7 people are selected at random, find the probability that they are fans of professional baseball.

You are answering if 7 *Americans* are selected at random, find the probability that they are fans for professional baseball.

Comment: ohh so am finding the probability if the people selected were only Americans  , and i should be finding the probability for random people as well not only Americans ? , but doesn't the question not specify and info on them being americans or not , or is the probability like 0.5 either a person being an american or not being one

Comment: I would find the probability of a person being American first - i.e. proportion of Americans to the total world population